# jq getting values in arrays

Tags: bash, jq

I am playing with the discogs api.

If I run this

`curl https://api.discogs.com/artists/92476/releases?per_page=2 --user-agent "FooBarApp/3.0" | jq .releases`

As expected I get

```
[
  {
    "id": 863260,
    "status": "Accepted",
    "type": "release",
    "format": "12\", Single",
    "label": "EMI America",
    "title": "Get Up And Jump / Baby Appeal",
    "resource_url": "https://api.discogs.com/releases/863260",
    "role": "Main",
    "artist": "The Red Hot Chili Peppers*",
    "year": 1984,
    "thumb": "",
    "stats": {
      "community": {
        "in_wantlist": 138,
        "in_collection": 198
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 42499,
    "title": "The Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "type": "master",
    "main_release": 687880,
    "artist": "The Red Hot Chili Peppers*",
    "role": "Main",
    "resource_url": "https://api.discogs.com/masters/42499",
    "year": 1984,
    "thumb": "",
    "stats": {
      "community": {
        "in_wantlist": 1209,
        "in_collection": 995
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now from what I have read online, the correct way to print the values "id" would be like this

`curl https://api.discogs.com/artists/92476/releases?per_page=2 --user-agent "FooBarApp/3.0" | jq .releases.id`

But I get

`jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "id"`

Same result if I try

`curl https://api.discogs.com/artists/92476/releases?per_page=2 --user-agent "FooBarApp/3.0" | jq '.[].id'`

Does anyone know why this isn't working? What I expect is

```
863260
42499
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since `releases` is an array you need to do this:

`curl https://api.discogs.com/artists/92476/releases?per_page=2 --user-agent "FooBarApp/3.0" | jq .releases[].id`

notice the `[]` after `releases`

```
$ curl https://api.discogs.com/artists/92476/releases?per_page=2 --user-agent "FooBarApp/3.0" | jq .releases[].id
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   912  100   912    0     0   4301      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4322
863260
42499
$
```